# Scala underscore notation for map and filter

Tags: scala

Say I have the following code:

```
val a: List[(Int, String)] = List((1,"A"),(2,"B"),(3,"C"))
val b: List[String] = List("A","C","E")
```

I can do:

```
a.map{case (fst,snd) => (fst,snd + "a")}
a.filter{case (_,snd) => b.contains(snd)}
```

But why can't I do:

```
a.map((_._1,_._2 + "a"))
a.filter(b.contains(_._2))
```

Is there a way to accomplish this using underscore notation, or am I forced here?

Comment: `val b: List[Int] = List("A","C","E")`  should be `val b: List[String] = List("A","C","E")` I guess otherwise its a compilation error

Comment: `val b: List[Int] = List("A","C","E")` would work only if you have implicits defined.

Comment: Ping - have either of the below responses answered your question?

Comment: Yeah thanks. I marked as answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the example:

```
a.map((_._1,_._2 + "a"))
```

Each *placeholder* (i.e. each underscore/`_`) introduces *a new parameter* in the argument expression.

[To cite the Scala spec](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/009e59a8a66fd21f62a7504fb354792495cb6528/spec/06-expressions.md#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions)

> An expression (of syntactic category `Expr`)
>   may contain embedded underscore symbols `_` at places where identifiers
>   are legal. Such an expression represents an anonymous function where subsequent
>   occurrences of underscores denote successive parameters.
>
> *[...]*
>
> The anonymous functions in the left column use placeholder
>   syntax. Each of these is equivalent to the anonymous function on its right.
>
> ```
> |---------------------------|----------------------------|
> |`_ + 1`                    | `x => x + 1`               |
> |`_ * _`                    | `(x1, x2) => x1 * x2`      |
> |`(_: Int) * 2`             | `(x: Int) => (x: Int) * 2` |
> |`if (_) x else y`          | `z => if (z) x else y`     |
> |`_.map(f)`                 | `x => x.map(f)`            |
> |`_.map(_ + 1)`             | `x => x.map(y => y + 1)`   |
> ```

You'll have to use the expanded forms when you need to use a given parameter more than once. So your example has to be rewritten as:

```
a.map(x => (x._1, x._2 + "a"))
```

---

For the example

```
a.filter(b.contains(_._2))
```

The problem is that you are effectively passing in an anonymous function to `contains` rather than `filter`, so you won't be able to use underscore notation here either. Instead you'll have to write

```
a.filter(x => b.contains(x._2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do

```
a.map((_._1,_._2 + "a"))
```

because `_` will match the elements of the *iterable* for each iteration. The first `_` will match with the elements of the first iterable and second `_` will match with the elements of the second iterable and so on. _._1 will match the first element of *tupled elements* of the *first iterable*, but _._2 will try to get the second element of `tupled elements` of second iterable. **As there is no *second iterable*, Scala compiler would throw compilation error**

In your second line of code

```
a.filter(b.contains(_._2))
```

**`_._2` tries to get the second element of tupled iterable of `b`, but `b` is not a tupled iterable. `b` is simply a iterable of *String*.**

to make it work you can do

```
a.map(x => (x._1, x._2 + "a"))
a.filter(x => b.contains(x._2))
```